# Not able to hit federation service identifier on ADFS installed on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I have installed ADFS on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am able to hit the following URLs:-
https://hostname.test.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx
https://hostname.test.com/adfs/services/trust/mex

and even the login is successful on ADFs using idpinitiatedsignon.
However I am unable to create SP initiated flow on it. I am unable to hit the following URL :-

https://hostname.test.com/adfs/services/trust/

that is present in Federation Service Identifier in the Federation Service Properties. 
This URL returns :-

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Comment: Any idea anyone?